# Qual a explicação para a seguinte questão

Tags: java, lógica, for

Essa é um questão do simulado da certificação java do site Whizlabs.

```
public class Whizlabs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] testData = {1, 2, 3};
        for(abc){
        }
    }
}
```

A pergunta é a seguinte: "Choose the option can replace the text "abc" in the above code."
(Select 2 options)

A. `int i : testData`

B. `int i = 0; i < 1; i++`

C. `i++`

D. `;i++; 1 < 1;`

E. `;i < 1; 0`

A resposta correta é a letra "A" e "B". Porque? Não entendi a resposta.

Comment: Você sabe como funciona um `for`? O que é um `for`? Entende a sintaxe dele? Tem dúvida no que?

Comment: No caso a questão está apenas pedindo para percorrer os arrays usando for, é isso? Porque sendo assim a letra "B" não deveria ser `i <= 1` ou `i < 2`?

Comment: É o que parece, apesar de não fazer nada útil, compilaria, as outras três opções não.

Comment: Agora entendi, então não há necessidade de percorrer todo o array, por isso a parte da letra "B" `i<1` está correta, porque compilaria normalmente. No fim o único erro foi minha falta de atenção. Obrigado

Comment: De fato me parece que só querem saber quais tem a sintaxe certa, já que não tem um objetivo definido, apenas algo que pode ser colocado que vai funcionar de alguma forma. Tem muita pergunta é que até mais entendê-la do que o conhecimento em si.

Answer (score 1):

A resposta é a letra A. O que a questão quer é iterar o array.

```
int[] testData = {1, 2, 3};
for(int i : testData){
     System.out.println(i);
}
```

É o mesmo que fazer:

```
int[] testData = {1, 2, 3};
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
     System.out.println(i);
}
```